# how to fix unauthorized error 401. i got the error after injecting the credentials

Tags: java, service, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, soapui

```
I'm getting unauthorized error when trying to access the endpoint.(Please see logs below)

RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray resource.getRepository() Before Change === ****
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray 1
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray credentials.getUsername() = ****
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray credentials.getPassword() = ****
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray resource.getRepository().toString().toLowerCase() = ****
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray 3
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray 4
RepositoryContent.retrieveContentByteArray 5
RepositoryContent.register RegistryURL = http://mylink:3001/services/core/runtime/RegistryService
RepositoryContent.register context.getLocale() = null
RepositoryContent.register context.getToken() = null
RepositoryContent.register context.getIdentities() = *****
RepositoryContent.register context.getProfiles() = null
RepositoryContent.register context.getRuntimeProperties() = null
RepositoryContent.register RegistryControl.getEndpoint()() = 



http://mylink:3001/services/core/runtime/RegistryService
   AxisFault
   faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
   faultSubcode: 
   faultString: (401)Unauthorized
   faultActor: 
   faultNode: 
   faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  401
```

I have a singleton class which configure the service endpoints and security credentials ( see below)

```
    private RepositoryContent() {

    ServiceControlHelper.configureEndPoint(contextRegistryControl, "endpoint");

    credentials = ServiceControlHelper.configureEndPoint(queryServiceControl, "endpoint");
            ServiceControlHelper.configureEndPoint(objectServiceControl, "endpoint");
        }
```

And it injects the same into the identity header

```
RepositoryIdentity[] identities = new RepositoryIdentity[1];
identities[0] = new RepositoryIdentity(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword(),
resource.getRepository().toString().toLowerCase(), "");
ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext();
context.setIdentities(identities);
```

I tested the service in soap ui and it is not working when we add header 
authorization.

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:soapui]?

Comment: I just tested if i can connect to the endpoint using soap ui